# Check constraint using function

Tags: sql-server, constraints, sql-function, check-constraint

I have a table called Users with these columns: UserID (int) UserName (nvarchar), Password (nvarchar), isActive (bit - true/false).

What I want to do is to allow insert of duplicate username only if all other users with this username are disabled.

I created this function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[isActiveUsername]
    (@username nvarchar(15))
RETURNS bit
AS

BEGIN

IF EXISTS
            (
                SELECT * 
                FROM Users
                WHERE isActive = 1 AND UserName = @username
            )
            RETURN 1
    RETURN 0
END
```

This function will return true if there's active user with this username, otherwise false.

After that, I created check constraint based on the returned value from this function:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users]  
WITH NOCHECK ADD CHECK  (([dbo].[isActiveUsername]([UserName])=(0)))
```

If there's no active user with this username, allow insert... 
But for some reason when I try to insert a new user, no metter what username I try, I get this error:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__Users__UserName__4D94879B". The conflict occurred in database "Chat", table "dbo.Users", column 'UserName'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Help please? 
Many thanks!!

Comment: yes, i set isActive = 1

Comment: if there's active user with this username return true (1),
if there's no acctive user return false (0). 

allow insert if there is no active user (if 0 returned)

Comment: SQL Server 2012 Express

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `INSERT` happens BEFORE your `CHECK` constraint runs, so there is always an user in the table before the function runs. Change your function to this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[isActiveUsername]
    (@username nvarchar(15))
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    IF  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE isActive = 1 AND UserName = @username) > 1
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1
    END

    RETURN 0

END
```

Comment: This is the reason why the function doesnt, er _function_, as written, but I think the filtered index is a better alternative.

Comment: @NathanSkerl I agree, but didn't see that it was SQL2012 till just now. This method will work in SQL2005.

Comment: @DavidG Very helpful answer. would you know by chance the reason why it works this way?
It does not sound logical to me, I would have expected that the function runs first, and the insert only applies if the function result is considered safe.

Answer (score 3):

For MSSQL 2008 and above, create a [filtered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) on isActive:

```
create unique index ux_UserName on dbo.Users(Username) where isActive = 1;
```

This allows you to enforce uniqueness on a subset of data.